# json issues with fullCalendar in asp.net

Tags: javascript, json, vb.net, callback, fullcalendar

I am working on providing a Event Calendar in asp.net getting data from sqlserver 2008R2 database, these are the details:

STORED PROCEDURE

...

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetCalendarData]
@fromVisitPlanDate varchar(50),
@toVisitPlanDate varchar(50),
@employeeId int
AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;

SELECT 
    cvp.clientVisitPlanId as id, 
    cvp.clientVisitPlanDay as start, 
    cvp.clientVisitPlanDay as [end],  
    title = substring(
                                (SELECT ( 'Buyer Code ' + ci.clientName+' Name '+ci.clientOrganization)
                                 FOR XML PATH( '' )
                                ), 1, 1000 
                      ) 
FROM
clientVisitPlan as cvp 
inner join clientInformation as ci on ci.clientId=cvp.clientId 
WHERE
cvp.employeeId=@employeeId and 
cvp.clientVisitPlanDay between cast(@fromVisitPlanDate as nvarchar(50)) and cast(@toVisitPlanDate as nvarchar(50))

END
```

...
My ASPX page code is
...

```
<section class="content">
   <div id="calendar"></div> 
</section>
```

...
My Javascript Code is
...

```
 document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {

    var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');

    var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
                    plugins: ['bootstrap','dayGrid','timeGrid'],
        events: function (start, end, timezone, callback) {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "ClientVisitCalendar.aspx/GetCalendarData",
                contentType: "application/json",
                timeZone: 'UTC',
                success: function (data) {
                    var events = [];
                    var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(data.d);
                    alert(data.d.toString());
                    $(obj).each(function () {
                        events.push({
                            id: $(this).attr('id'),
                            title: $(this).attr('title'),
                            start: $(this).attr('start'),
                            end: $(this).attr('[end]')

                        });
                    });
                    callback(events);
                },
                error: function (xhr, status, error) { }
            });
        }
    });
    calendar.render();
});
```

...
My Page Behind code is
...

```
Public Shared Function GetCalendarData()
    Dim daresult As String = Nothing
    Dim ds As DataSet = New DataSet()
    Dim dt As DataTable = New DataTable()
    Dim conn As String
    conn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("HYDRA").ConnectionString
    Dim tempEmployeeId As Integer = HttpContext.Current.Session("employeeId")
    tempEmployeeId = 18
    Dim tempDate As DateTime
    tempDate = DateTime.Now
    Dim StartDate As DateTime
    StartDate = New DateTime(tempDate.Year, tempDate.Month, 1)
    StartDate = StartDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")
    Dim EndDate As DateTime
    EndDate = StartDate.AddMonths(1).AddDays(-1)
    EndDate = EndDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")
    Using sqlConn As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection(conn)
        sqlConn.Open()
        Using sqlCmd As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand("GetCalendarData", sqlConn)
            sqlCmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@fromVisitPlanDate", StartDate))
            sqlCmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@toVisitPlanDate", EndDate))
            sqlCmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@employeeId", tempEmployeeId))
            sqlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
            Dim ad As SqlDataAdapter = New SqlDataAdapter(sqlCmd)
            ad.Fill(dt)
        End Using
        sqlConn.Close()
    End Using
    If dt.Rows.Count > 0 Then
        ds.Tables.Add(dt)
        daresult = DataSetToJSON(ds)
    End If
    daresult = Nothing
    daresult = GetJson(dt)
    Return daresult
End Function

Public Shared Function DataSetToJSON(ByVal ds As DataSet) As String
    Dim dict As Dictionary(Of String, Object) = New Dictionary(Of String, Object)()
    For Each dt As DataTable In ds.Tables
        Dim arr As Object() = New Object(dt.Rows.Count + 1 - 1) {}
        For i As Integer = 0 To dt.Rows.Count - 1
            arr(i) = dt.Rows(i).ItemArray
        Next
        dict.Add(dt.TableName, arr)
    Next
    Dim json As JavaScriptSerializer = New JavaScriptSerializer()
    Return json.Serialize(dict)
End Function
```

...

The generated JSON from web-method is

```
[{
  "id": 3,
  "start": "\/Date(1575399600000)\/",
  "end": "\/Date(1575399600000)\/",
  "title": "Buyer Code N133CHTKH Name NADEEM ASHFAQ AND CO"
}, {
  "id": 4,
  "start": "\/Date(1576436400000)\/",
  "end": "\/Date(1576436400000)\/",
  "title": "Buyer Code A359CHTKH Name AAMIR INTERNATIONAL"
}]
```

The issue i am facing is that it does not show the json data in fullcalendar and the error given is
callback is not a function

```
Uncaught TypeError: callback is not a function
    at Object.success (ClientVisitCalendar.aspx:135)
    at i (jQuery-2.2.0.min.js:2)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jQuery-2.2.0.min.js:2)
    at z (jQuery-2.2.0.min.js:4)
    at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (jQuery-2.2.0.min.js:4)
```

Comment: You are mangling togethersyntax from fullCalendar v3 and v4. This will not work, they are very different. Read the v4 documentation carefully, especially to check the parameters which are passed to the "events" callback: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/events-function . Also, if you are reading from examples online, make sure you check which version of fullCalendar they apply to.

Comment: P.S. Also you will need momentJS in order to read the dates being output by your WebMethod. fullCalendar v4 no longer uses momentJS by default to parse dates, so you need to [parse the date yourself via momentJS](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/asp-net-json-date/) before passing it to fullCalendar, as the native JS Date parser cannot interpret dates in that format. Alternatively, get your server to output the dates in a sane format. Ideally, don't use WebMethods, use a Web API project instead.

Comment: And don't use SQL 2008, it's out of support - you need to upgrade urgently. (Although your database code is entirely irrelevant to the question, actually).

Comment: i modified the javascript like this:                                                                       
         start: moment($(this).attr('start'), 'YYYY-DD-MM'),
         end: moment($(this).attr('[end]'), 'YYYY-DD-MM')                                       
but I still got the same callback is not a function also can u give me a code example of fullcalendar v4 if possible

Comment: `callback is not a function` does not occur because of the date format. That is a separate issue. It occurs because you have not read the documentation properly and understood which parameters are passed to the events function. Again, please read https://fullcalendar.io/docs/events-function **carefully** and compare it to your version. You'll note that in the documentation it says you should define the function as `function( fetchInfo, successCallback, failureCallback ) { }`, but you've defined it as `function (start, end, timezone, callback) { }`...get the idea yet?

Comment: You might also want to look at the version 3 documentation at https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v3/events-function and see how it compares to your current code. It might help you understand the difference.